# How to check if previous label has the same value as something in an array

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a "Snap!" game. I'm trying to check if the previous text of a label corresponds to the current text of a label, e.g. if the previous text of a label was `bee`, and the current display is `bee` it will display, 'Snap!'.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOne.Click
        Dim imageResourceNames = {"Owl", "Bee", "Bird", "Frog", "Duck"}
        Dim randImage As New Random
        Dim index = randImage.Next(imageResourceNames.Length)
        Dim imageResourceName = imageResourceNames(index)
        Dim img = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageResourceName), Image)

        picOne.Image = img
        picOne.Visible = True
        lblDisplay.Text = imageResourceNames(Index)
        btnOne.Enabled = False

        If lblDisplay.Text = imageResourceName Then
            Console.WriteLine("snap!")
            lblDisplay.Text = "Snap!"
        End If

    End Sub
```

While I am not getting errors, it seems that the label is always displaying `'Snap!'`. If anyone knows how to fix this I would really appreciate it!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set both `imageResourceName` & `lblDisplay.Text` to the same value, `imageResourceNames(index)`. So when you then your if `lblDisplay.Text = imageResourceName` is always going to be executed.

---

You haven't shown enough code to give a definitive answer as to how to make it work, but something like this would be close:

```
Private CurrentImageResourceName As String = String.Empty

Private Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOne.Click
    Dim imageResourceNames = {"Owl", "Bee", "Bird", "Frog", "Duck"}
    Dim randImage As New Random
    Dim index = randImage.Next(imageResourceNames.Length)
    Dim imageResourceName = imageResourceNames(index)
    Dim img = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageResourceName), Image)

    picOne.Image = img
    picOne.Visible = True
    btnOne.Enabled = False

    If CurrentImageResourceName = imageResourceName Then
        Console.WriteLine("snap!")
        lblDisplay.Text = "Snap!"
    End If
    
    CurrentImageResourceName = imageResourceName
End Sub
```

You'll need to refactor that to get it to work the way you want.

Comment: I understand! But how would you overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

A `Label` is not a data store so stop treating it like one. It's just to display text to the user. If you want to know what the previous value was then store it in a variable.

```vb
Private previousImageResourceName As String
Private currentImageResourceName As String
Private randImage As New Random
```

and:

```vb
Dim imageResourceNames = {"Owl", "Bee", "Bird", "Frog", "Duck"}
Dim index = randImage.Next(imageResourceNames.Length)

previousImageResourceName = currentImageResourceName
currentImageResourceName = imageResourceNames(index)

Dim img = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageResourceName), Image)

picOne.Image = img
picOne.Visible = True
lblDisplay.Text = currentImageResourceName
btnOne.Enabled = False

If currentImageResourceName = previousImageResourceName Then
    Console.WriteLine("snap!")
    lblDisplay.Text = "Snap!"
End If
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "is not a data store so stop treating it like one"?